# Future Dates not showing as Invalid Age Range

Tags: sql, t-sql

my query below does not seem to be detecting dob that have a future year as an Invalid Age Range. Can anyone shed some insight as to what needs to be changed?

```
WITH AgeData as
(
 SELECT [sex],
     [dob],
     DATEDIFF(YEAR, [dob], GETDATE()) AS [AGE]
  FROM dbo.Farmers
),
GroupAge AS
(
  SELECT [sex],
     [dob],      
     CASE
         WHEN AGE < 24 THEN '24 and Under'
         WHEN AGE BETWEEN 25 AND 30 THEN '25 - 30'
         WHEN AGE BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31 - 40'
         WHEN AGE BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN '41 - 50'
         WHEN AGE > 50 THEN '50 and Over'
         ELSE 'Invalid Birthdate'
     END AS [Age Groups]
 FROM AgeData
)
SELECT
[Age Groups],
COUNT(CASE WHEN sex = 1 THEN 1 END) AS [Female Farmers],
COUNT(CASE WHEN sex = 2 THEN 2 END) AS [Male Farmers] 
FROM GroupAge
GROUP BY [Age Groups]
ORDER BY [Age Groups] ASC;
```

Comment: `... WHEN AGE < 24 AND AGE >= 0 THEN ...` Otherwise negative year olds get sorted in the `'24 and Under'` category.

Comment: But there can still be future dates in there, as for any dates with the same year `datediff(year...)` returns `0`.

Comment: Note that `DateDiff` returns the difference in crossings of [datepart boundaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#datepart-boundaries). That isn't usually what `Age` represents, e.g. from 31 October 2000 to 14 February 2001 is one year because one _year_ boundary was crossed.

Answer (score 2):

`CASE` statements stops at first valid argument.

Future dates are negative as age, so always less than 24.

So you should change your first `WHEN`:

`WHEN AGE < 24 AND AGE >= 0 THEN '24 and Under'`

Answer (score 2):

Your ELSE case is never reached. Change your `CASE` expression to evaluate the comparisons in only one direction, for example:

```
CASE
  WHEN AGE > 50 THEN '51 and Over'
  WHEN AGE > 40 THEN '41 - 50'
  WHEN AGE > 30 THEN '31 - 40'
  WHEN AGE > 24 THEN '25 - 30'
  WHEN AGE >= 0 THEN '24 and Under'
  ELSE 'Invalid Birthdate'
END AS [Age Groups]
```